# Are there any studies that prove the effectiveness of saw palmetto for restoring hair in the bald places and stop hair fall?

Tags: hair, hairloss, clinical-study, herbs

I'm looking for studies apart from the ones in the third link in my question, that prove the efficacy of saw palmetto in 1) stop hair fall, and 2) growing back hair in the places of the scalp where the hair was lost.

I'm aware of the fact that theoretically saw palmetto blocks the enzyme that converts testoterone into DHT, and hence it should be effective. See for example- https://www.healthline.com/health/saw-palmetto-hair-loss#saw-palmetto, https://articles.mercola.com/sites/articles/archive/2018/07/30/saw-palmetto-for-alopecia.aspx, and in fact, two such studies have been mentioned here- https://blog.nutrafol.com/2017/03/12/saw-palmetto-benefits-hair-growth/ (read the description in the link please). But still, more studies in this regard would be crucial to prove its effectiveness. Thank you!

Comment: Welcome to MedicalSciences.SE. where did you read that saw palmetto blocks the enzyme that converts testoterone into DHT? For [reasons mentioned in this post](https://medicalsciences.meta.stackexchange.com/q/411) and in [ask], we require prior research information when asking questions. Please help us to help you and [edit] your question to provide more information on what you have read on this subject, what made you ask this question, and any problems you are having understanding your research. This helps to provide an answer which will be more helpful.

Comment: @ChrisRogers Thanjs for your comment-I edited the questions with the necessary links.

Answer (score 1):

These are extracts and links:

- Other proposed treatments include saw palmetto extract (Serenoa Repens); prostaglandin analogs like latanoprost and bimatoprost, which may be cost prohibitive
  (https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/books/NBK430924/)
- Serenoa repens(commonly called Saw Palmetto) extracts promote hair regeneration and repair of hair loss mouse models by activating TGF-β and mitochondrial signaling pathway.
  (https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/m/pubmed/29949176/)
- A randomized, double-blind, placebo-controlled trial to determine the effectiveness of botanically derived inhibitors of 5-alpha-reductase in the treatment of androgenetic alopecia
- CONCLUSIONS: This study establishes the effectiveness of naturally occurring 5AR inhibitors against AGA for the first time, and justifies the expansion to larger trials.(https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/m/pubmed/12006122/)
- We can summarize our results by observing that Serenoa repens could lead to an improvement of androgenetic alopecia, while finasteride confirmed its efficacy. 
  (https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/m/pubmed/23298508/)